# How to save multiple Maple files (.mw) as pdf at once?

Tags: python, pdf, maple

I have a large collection of Maple files (.mw) that I need to convert into PDF format. Manually opening each file in Maple and exporting them one by one would be extremely time-consuming. I'm looking for a faster way to convert multiple files to PDF, such as using a programming language like Python or perhaps Maple's built-in programming capabilities.

I have tried making a small Python-script by using the library subprocess, but I cannot make it work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.